# Сравнение строк двух разных датафреймов pandas по нескольким условиям

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть два датафрейма, нужно сравнить данные по нескольким условиям столбцов в нужной строке и вписать данные одного датафрейма в другой.
Я решил это с помощью вложенных циклов

```
for i in range(df_mi.shape[0]):
    for j in range(df_pz.shape[0]):   
        if (df_mi.iloc[i].A == df_pz.iloc[j].A) and (df_mi.iloc[i].C >= df_pz.iloc[j].C) and (df_mi.iloc[i].D <= df_pz.iloc[j].D) :
            df_mi.iloc[i].new = df_pz.iloc[j].J
```

Но способ очень медленный.
Есть ли идеи как сделать быстрее?

Comment: А, стоп, вам реально нужно "все со всеми" сравнивать, а не соответствующие строки двух датафреймов? А то я в решении посчитал, что соответствующие сравниваются

Answer (score 0):

Обычно в `Pandas` всё можно сделать без циклов. Вот вам пример приближенный к вашему:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 =  pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(1000,5))
df2 =  pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(1000,5))
df1.columns = list('ABCDJ')
df2.columns = list('ABCDJ')

cond = (df1.C <= df2.C) & (df1.D >= df2.D)
df1.loc[cond, 'new'] = df1.loc[cond, 'J']
```

Основное, что нужно иметь в виду:

- Условия выборки обязательно нужно писать в скобках и соединять между собой через побитовые операции `&` и `|` (а не через логические `and` и `or`), условий можно писать сколько угодно
- В новый столбец данные можно записать только через индексную нотацию `['new']`, а как вы написали через точку `.new` так запись в новый столбец не работает, это сработает только если такой столбец уже есть, тогда `Pandas` сделает всё что нужно за вас и обеспечит доступ
- Размер `Series` слева и справа от знака присваивания должен быть одинаковый, поэтому я заранее создаю битовую маску, сохраняю её в переменную и использую `.loc[]` нотацию с этой маской с обеих сторон `=`

Comment: Замените df_mi.shape[0] на len_df_mi=df_mi.shape[0] в range и для другого,чуть быстрее.

Answer (score 0):

Судя по всему, вы хотите сравнить строки двух разных датафреймов и вписать данные одного датафрейма в другой, если выполнено несколько условий на столбцы. Один из способов ускорения вашего кода состоит в том, чтобы использовать метод `apply` для применения функции к каждой строке датафрейма. Этот метод обычно работает быстрее, чем циклы, так как он использует векторизованные операции вместо последовательных операций над каждым элементом.

Ниже приведен пример того, как это может выглядеть:

```
def compare_rows(row):
    for i in range(df_pz.shape[0]):
        if (row.A == df_pz.iloc[i].A) and (row.C >= df_pz.iloc[i].C) and (row.D <= df_pz.iloc[i].D):
            return df_pz.iloc[i].J
    return row.new

df_mi['new'] = df_mi.apply(compare_rows, axis=1)
```

Обратите внимание, что в функции compare_rows мы используем текущую строку датафрейма `df_mi`, которая передается в качестве аргумента функции. Мы сравниваем эту строку с каждой строкой датафрейма `df_pz`, и если все условия выполнены, мы возвращаем значение из столбца `J` датафрейма `df_pz`. Если ни одно из условий не выполнено, мы возвращаем значение из столбца new датафрейма `df_mi`.

Метод `apply` применяет функцию `compare_rows` к каждой строке датафрейма `df_mi` и возвращает результат в виде нового столбца `new`.

Этот код должен работать быстрее, чем ваш исходный код с вложенными циклами, так как он использует векторизованные операции вместо последовательных операций над каждым элементом.

Есть еще несколько способов, которые могут ускорить ваш код. Один из них состоит в том, чтобы использовать метод merge для слияния датафреймов `df_mi` и `df_pz` по нужным условиям. Этот метод обычно работает быстрее, чем циклы, так как он использует внутренние алгоритмы Pandas для слияния датафреймов.

Ниже приведен пример того, как это может выглядеть:

```
df_merged = df_mi.merge(df_pz, on=['A', 'C', 'D'], how='inner')
df_mi['new'] = df_merged['J']
```

Метод merge сливает датафреймы `df_mi` и `df_pz` по столбцам `A, C и D`, и возвращает результат в виде нового датафрейма `df_merged`. Затем мы присваиваем значения из столбца `J` датафрейма `df_merged` столбцу `new` датафрейма `df_mi`.